# Regular expression for words containing single 1 and even number of 0s

Tags: regular-expressions

What would be a regular expression for the language of words containing a single 1 and an even number of 0s?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Basically stuck on the whole part. I tried splitting them up into two different expressions, one for a single 1 and one for an even number of 0's but still got no where

Answer (score 3):

If a word contains exactly one 1 and an even number of zeroes, then we can decompose it in one of two different ways:

1. An even number of 0s, followed by 1, followed by an even number of 0s.
2. An odd number of 0s, followed by 1, followed by an odd number of 0s.

You take it from here.